# Javascript mysterious Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, uncaught-exception

I have a credit card form and I perform on the fly data validation with JS. For some reason the data validation doesn't work for the expiration month and year fields: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Bellow is the html:

```
  <div class="controls controls-row">
  <label class="h2_style"><fmt:message key='payment_exp'/><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input class="span1 noBottomMargin" maxlength='2' type='text' data-encrypted-name='expiration_month' id='credit_card_expiration_month' value='11' onChange="validateCreditCardExpMonth('credit_card_expiration_month','err_expiration',<fmt:message key='forms.card_date'/>);"></input>
  <span><input class="span1 noBottomMargin" maxlength='4' type='text' data-encrypted-name='expiration_year' id='credit_card_expiration_year' value='2015' onChange="validateCreditCardExpYear('credit_card_expiration_year','err_expiration',<fmt:message key='forms.card_date'/>);"></input></span>
  <p class="error" id="err_expiration"></p>
  <br />
```

And the JS:

```
function validateCreditCardExpMonth(id,err_id,err){
var err_text=err;
var number = document.getElementById(id).value;
var reg = new RegExp('^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$', 'i');
if(reg.test(number)){
    document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor="green";
    document.getElementById(err_id).innerHTML="";
}
else{
    document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor="red";
    document.getElementById(err_id).innerHTML=err_text;
}
}


function validateCreditCardExpYear(id,err_id,err){
var err_text=err;
var number = document.getElementById(id).value;
var reg = new RegExp('^(201[3-9]|202[0-3])$', 'i');
if(reg.test(number)){
    document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor="green";
    document.getElementById(err_id).innerHTML="";
}
else{
    document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor="red";
    document.getElementById(err_id).innerHTML=err_text;
}
}
```

I checked the syntax of the onChange against the other fields and I don't see any difference hence I don't understand why these 2 aren't working. As I am far from being a JS expert I thought I run the issue here (maybe there is an obvious mistake...)

I also checked the jstl messages and the error is not coming from there.

Do you see what is causing the issue?

Comment: You should use a regex literal.

Comment: Read the generated HTML source.

Comment: Obvious but thanks for the pointing it out: I had a closer look to the generated HTML and the error message is "date d'expiration non valide" so I'm guessing that the ' of d'expiration is causing the issue

Comment: @user2177336: I'll delete my answer, since it's slightly wide of the mark. (Quite similar, but not quite the same.) Probably best to post your comment above as an answer, and then accept it when SO lets you (in ~48 hours).

Answer (score 0):

Corrected html:

You can use:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <label class="h2_style"><fmt:message key='payment_exp'/><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input class="span1 noBottomMargin" maxlength='2' type='text' data-encrypted-name='expiration_month' id='credit_card_expiration_month' value='11' onChange="validateCreditCardExpMonth('credit_card_expiration_month','err_expiration','Error Exp');"></input>
  <span><input class="span1 noBottomMargin" maxlength='4' type='text' data-encrypted-name='expiration_year' id='credit_card_expiration_year' value='2015' onChange="validateCreditCardExpYear('credit_card_expiration_year','err_expiration','Error Year');"></input></span>
  <p class="error" id="err_expiration"></p>
  <br />
```

or:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <label class="h2_style"><fmt:message key='payment_exp'/><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input class="span1 noBottomMargin" maxlength='2' type='text' data-encrypted-name='expiration_month' id='credit_card_expiration_month' value='11' onChange="validateCreditCardExpMonth('credit_card_expiration_month','err_expiration','<fmt:message key=\'forms.card_date\'/>');"></input>
  <span><input class="span1 noBottomMargin" maxlength='4' type='text' data-encrypted-name='expiration_year' id='credit_card_expiration_year' value='2015' onChange="validateCreditCardExpYear('credit_card_expiration_year','err_expiration','<fmt:message key=\'forms.card_date\'/>');"></input></span>
  <p class="error" id="err_expiration"></p>
  <br />
```

Depending on what you want to pass to the "validateCreditCardExpYear" function.

You are passing an incorrect formatted string to the last parameter in  validateCreditCardExpYear function.